# Interpretation of "from...to" vs "until"

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, till-until

I want to understand the difference between these two phrases. Suppose the following example:

"John will be in New York from Thursday to Saturday" .

"John will be in New York until Saturday".

Lets start with the first example. When we use "from...to" do we imply that before Tuesday and after Saturday John won't be in New York? If this is what implies the sentence then we should be more strict as John could be in New York even one month ago.

Now with the second example. Again does this sentence mean that before Saturday John was in New York and after Saturday John wasn't in New York?

I am not asking if we treat until inclusively or exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in pointing out the differences in implication between the two phrases in the context of the example. I'll clarify the differences in meaning for both phrases, focusing on the time period each implies for John's presence in New York.

"John will be in New York from Thursday to Saturday": This phrase implies that John will be in New York for a continuous period starting on Thursday and ending on Saturday. It does not necessarily mean that John wasn't in New York before Thursday or that he will not be in New York after Saturday. However, the common interpretation is that John's presence in New York before and after the specified period is less likely or uncertain. It does not explicitly restrict John's presence at any specific time before or after the given time frame.

"John will be in New York until Saturday": This phrase suggests that John will be in New York continuously up to and including Saturday. It implies that John was already in New York before this time frame, and it does not necessarily mean that John will not be in New York after Saturday. However, it is commonly interpreted that John's presence in New York after Saturday is unlikely or uncertain. Similar to the first phrase, it does not explicitly restrict John's presence at any specific time before the given time frame.

Answer (score 0):

John will be in New York from Thursday to Saturday" tells us only that during the forthcoming period Thursday-Friday-Saturday John will be in NY. This is usually on the assumption that the speaker is referring to the shortest such period, and not to (for example) next Friday and a Sunday three weeks later. We understand it as a forthcoming period that has not yet started, because the speaker used the future “will be”. The statement tells us nothing about where John was, is or will be outside that period.

If we want to say this is the only time that he visits NY, we have to say so explicitly by writing more. “He will never been to NY until Thursday. He will be there Thursday to Saturday. He will never visit NY again.”

"John will be in New York until Saturday" tells us only that John will be in NY during a period that ends on Saturday. The statement does not tell us when that period started, or that he is there now - although it is often be used in that way. It tells us nothing about where he has been until now, or where he will be before the period starts. Nor does it say where he will be after Saturday, although it is often used to imply that he will leave, and hence not be there on the next day, Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks about what these sentences **imply** about John's presence in New York before Thursday and after Saturday. The answer depends on whether *imply* in the question is interpreted in the narrow, strict sense of a logical relationship, or the broader, looser sense that includes conversational implicatures (matters of pragmatics).

So far as the meanings of the words *from, to* and *until* are concerned, these sentences do not tell us anything about John's presence in New York before Thursday or after Saturday. Logic alone does not allow us to derive from these sentences that John won't be in New York on Sunday, nor that he will be.

However, somebody who knew that John will be in New York on Sunday as well, would have said so: it would have been, under normal circumstances, bizarrely uncooperative (although still true) to say 'until Saturday', if one knew that John's presence in the city will extend to Sunday. Given what we know about how human beings normally communicate, we can then conclude that, so far as the speaker's knowledge goes, John won't be in New York on Sunday (even though we cannot conclude that from the content of the given sentences considered apart from the general conventions that govern human interaction). That can be expressed by saying that 'to/until Saturday', **conversationally implicates** (even though it does not logically imply) that John won't be in New York on Sunday.

In ordinary, casual communication, we rely on conversational implicatures all the time, and would do so in this case. In a setting in which something of great importance depended on full accuracy (e.g. in a legal proceeding), we would probably prefer to see formulations that do not require us to rely on conversational implicatures (such as 'John is scheduled to leave New York on Saturday evening').